Setting up the operation of the button (ICommand) depending on the selected row of the table (DataGrid)
I have one window WPF and 2 tables DataGrid. The DataContext is bound to the class PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel.cs.
PersonalTaskClassPicker.xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppTaskPlanner.PersonalTaskClassPicker"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfAppTaskPlanner.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfAppTaskPlanner"
        xmlns:taskClassDirectory="clr-namespace:Library.TaskClassDirectory;assembly=Library"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="850" Width="1500" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModels:OutputValueConverter x:Key="OutputValueConverter"></viewModels:OutputValueConverter>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomDataGridHeaderTemplate">
            <views:CustomDataGridHeader></views:CustomDataGridHeader>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <!--Other buttons-->
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="Удалить задачу"
                    Width="100" Height="40" Margin="15 5"
                    Command="{Binding RemoveTaskClassCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="Связанные задачи" Margin="0 5"></TextBlock>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridRelatedPersonalTaskClass"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTaskPerformerClass.PersonalTaskClassLists.RelatedList,
                  FallbackValue='SelectedTaskPerformerClass не не выбран'}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTaskClass, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Участок"
                                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomDataGridHeaderTemplate}"
                                        Binding="{Binding BrigadeIndex}"
                                        IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <!--Other DataGridTextColumns-->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <TextBlock Text="Удаленные задачи" Margin="0 5"></TextBlock>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridDeletedPersonalTaskClass"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTaskPerformerClass.PersonalTaskClassLists.DeletedList,
                    FallbackValue='SelectedTaskPerformerClass не не выбран'}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTaskClass, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Участок"
                                        HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomDataGridHeaderTemplate}"
                                        Binding="{Binding BrigadeIndex}"
                                        IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <!--Other DataGridTextColumns-->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>

PersonalTaskClassPicker.xaml.cs
public partial class PersonalTaskClassPicker
{
    public PersonalTaskClassPicker(ref TaskPerformerClass selectedTaskPerformerClass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel(ref selectedTaskPerformerClass);
    }
}

PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel.cs
public class PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel(ref TaskPerformerClass selectedTaskPerformerClass)
    {
        RemoveTaskClassCommand = new RelayCommand(RemoveTaskClass, CanRemoveTaskClass);
        // Other ICommand's
    }
}

BaseViewModel.cs
public class BaseViewModel : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
{
private TaskClass? _selectedTaskClass;
public TaskClass? SelectedTaskClass
    {
        get => _selectedTaskClass;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedTaskClass))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (SetField(ref _selectedTaskClass, value))
            {
                CallRaiseCanExecuteChanged(RemoveTaskClassCommand);
            }
        }
    }

private TaskPerformerClass? _selectedTaskPerformerClass;
public TaskPerformerClass? SelectedTaskPerformerClass
    {
        get => _selectedTaskPerformerClass;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTaskPerformerClass != value)
            {
                _selectedTaskPerformerClass = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

public ICommand? RemoveTaskClassCommand { get; protected init; }

public static void CallRaiseCanExecuteChanged(ICommand? command)
    {
        switch (command)
        {
            case AsyncRelayCommandWithParameter getToWorkCommand:
                getToWorkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                break;
            case RelayCommand getToWorkCommand:
                getToWorkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                break;
        }
    }

protected bool CanRemoveTaskClass(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is not PersonalTaskClassPicker
            {
                DataContext: PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel personalTaskClassPickerViewModel
            })
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (personalTaskClassPickerViewModel.SelectedTaskPerformerClass is null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("personalTaskClassPickerViewModel.SelectedTaskPerformerClass is null");
        }
        else
        {
            var taskPerformer = personalTaskClassPickerViewModel.SelectedTaskPerformerClass;
            if (SelectedTaskClass is not null
                && taskPerformer.PersonalTaskClassLists.RelatedList is not null
                && taskPerformer.PersonalTaskClassLists.RelatedList.Contains(SelectedTaskClass))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

protected void RemoveTaskClass(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is not PersonalTaskClassPicker
            {
                DataContext: PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel personalTaskClassPickerViewModel
            })
        {
            return;
        }
        if (personalTaskClassPickerViewModel.SelectedTaskPerformerClass is null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("personalTaskClassPickerViewModel.SelectedTaskPerformerClass is null");
        }
        else
        {
            var personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass =
                personalTaskClassPickerViewModel.SelectedTaskPerformerClass.PersonalTaskClassLists;
            var selectedTaskClass = SelectedTaskClass;

            if (selectedTaskClass is not null
                && personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.RelatedList is not null
                && personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.RelatedList.Contains(selectedTaskClass))
            {
                personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.RelatedList.Remove(selectedTaskClass);
                personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.DeletedList ??= new ObservableCollection<TaskClass>();
                personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.DeletedList.Add(selectedTaskClass);

                personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.OnPropertyChanged(
                    nameof(personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.RelatedList)
                );
                personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.OnPropertyChanged(
                    nameof(personalTaskClassListsOfTaskPerformerClass.DeletedList)
                );
                CallRaiseCanExecuteChanged(RemoveTaskClassCommand);
            }
        }
    }
}

BaseNotifyPropertyChanged.cs
public class BaseNotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object>? _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object>? canExecute = null)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) =>
            _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter ?? "<N/A>");

        public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter ?? "<N/A>");
        }

        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
    }

    //Other AsyncRelayCommand's
}

The WPF window is called from the main WPF window as follows:
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
//Other code

private static void OnEditPersonalTaskClassList(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is not TaskPerformerClass selectedTaskPerformerClass)
        {
            return;
        }

        var personalTaskClassEditor = new PersonalTaskClassPicker(ref selectedTaskPerformerClass);

        if (personalTaskClassEditor.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            //Other commands
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DataContext закрытого окна не является типом TaskPerformerClass");
        }
    }
}

TaskPerformerClass.cs
namespace Library.TaskPerformerDirectory;

public sealed class TaskPerformerClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Other private values
    private PersonalTaskClassCollection _personalTaskClassLists = null!;

    private TaskPerformerClass() { }

    public TaskPerformerClass(
        FullNameOfThePerson fullName,
        WorkDay workDay,
        CalendarYearOfTaskPerformer calendarYearOfTaskPerformer,
        int bitrixEmployeeIndex,
        List<Department>? bitrixEmployeeDepartmentList = null,
        TaskClass? actualTask = null
    )
    {
        //Other initializations of properties
        PersonalTaskClassLists = new PersonalTaskClassCollection(this);
    }

    //Other property

    public PersonalTaskClassCollection PersonalTaskClassLists
    {
        get => _personalTaskClassLists;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _personalTaskClassLists))
            {
                return;
            }

            _personalTaskClassLists = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

PersonalTaskClassCollection.cs
public sealed class PersonalTaskClassCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private int _taskPerformerClassId;
    private TaskPerformerClass _taskPerformerClass = null!;
    private ObservableCollection<TaskClass>? _completedList;
    private ObservableCollection<TaskClass>? _deletedList;
    private ObservableCollection<TaskClass>? _relatedList;

    private PersonalTaskClassCollection() { }
    public PersonalTaskClassCollection(TaskPerformerClass taskPerformerClass) =>
        TaskPerformerClass = taskPerformerClass;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            if (value == _id)
            {
                return;
            }

            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int TaskPerformerClassId
    {
        get => _taskPerformerClassId;
        set
        {
            if (value == _taskPerformerClassId)
            {
                return;
            }

            _taskPerformerClassId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public TaskPerformerClass TaskPerformerClass
    {
        get => _taskPerformerClass;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _taskPerformerClass))
            {
                return;
            }

            _taskPerformerClass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TaskClass>? RelatedList
    {
        get => _relatedList;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _relatedList))
            {
                return;
            }

            _relatedList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TaskClass>? DeletedList
    {
        get => _deletedList;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _deletedList))
            {
                return;
            }

            _deletedList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TaskClass>? CompletedList
    {
        get => _completedList;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _completedList))
            {
                return;
            }

            _completedList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

I don't see any point in describing the "TaskClass.cs" class. It's just a class that contains the properties of the task.
After randomly selecting a row in each of the 2 tables "DataGridRelatedPersonalTaskClass" and "DataGridDeletedPersonalTaskClass", the "RemoveTaskClassCommand" button will never be able to change the value of the "set" property "SelectedTaskClass". Thus, if you click on it, the next highlighted task in the "DataGridRelatedPersonalTaskClass" will be deleted.
Over time, I realized that if I highlighted each question in the tables, then the "SelectedItem" properties of each "DataGrid" continue to be active, but my "SelectedTaskClass" property is not always updated.Although the "IsMouseOver" property always correctly displays the row in which table I highlighted last.
I want to correctly configure the activity of the "RemoveTaskClassCommand" button when a row from the "DataGridRelatedPersonalTaskClass" table is selected. How to do it?

Firstly you need to read up on MvvM, you have PersonalTaskClassPicker in you MainVM, which is UI in View Model, another note is that this example is way too complex to jump on and help you. I got lost after base notify class. If you could simplify it then it would be easier for everyone to help. Perhaps you'll see that this code is a bit over complex for what it needs to do. Other than that happy to help

I have had further read and it looks like code behind of the user control that we can't see anywhere in xaml would be to blame first.


I have brought commands inheriting from INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand to a separate class Base NotifyPropertyChanged.cs.
I created the BaseViewModel.cs model because I have 2 WPF windows in which I need to use the same buttons and the same methods.


First, one important note. You pass the Window command parameter CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}".
Since this command is a ViewModel entity and according to MVVM rules, passing any UI element to ViewModel is prohibited, then your implementation actually completely destroys MVVM compliance.
On the essence of your question.
The most simplified example of one of the possible implementation options for your task.
namespace Core2024.SO.Zhan.question79147702
{
    public class SomeTextItem
    {
        private string _title = string.Empty;
        private string _text = string.Empty;
        private string _description = string.Empty;

        public string Title { get => _title; set => _title = value ?? string.Empty; }
        public string Text { get => _text; set => _text = value ?? string.Empty; }
        public string Description { get => _description; set => _description = value ?? string.Empty; }
    }
}

using Simplified; // This is the space with my implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand interfaces. You can use your own implementations instead.
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Core2024.SO.Zhan.question79147702
{
    public class SomeTextViewModel
    {
        private const string data = "After randomly selecting a row in each of the 2 tables \"DataGridRelatedPersonalTaskClass\" and \"DataGridDeletedPersonalTaskClass\", the \"RemoveTaskClassCommand\" button will never be able to change the value of the \"set\" property \"SelectedTaskClass\". Thus, if you click on it, the next highlighted task in the \"DataGridRelatedPersonalTaskClass\" will be deleted. Over time, I realized that if I highlighted each question in the tables, then the \"SelectedItem\" properties of each \"DataGrid\" continue to be active, but my \"SelectedTaskClass\" property is not always updated.Although the \"IsMouseOver\" property always correctly displays the row in which table I highlighted last.";
        private static IEnumerable<SomeTextItem> GetItems()
        {
            string[] split = data.Split();
            for (int i = 2; i < split.Length; i+=3)
            {
                yield return new SomeTextItem()
                {
                    Title = split[i-2],
                    Text = split[i-1],
                    Description = split[i]
                };
            }
        }
        public SomeTextViewModel()
        {
            TextItems = new ObservableCollection<SomeTextItem>(GetItems());
            RemoveTextItem = new RelayCommand<SomeTextItem>
            (
                item => TextItems.Remove(item),
                item => TextItems.Contains(item)
            );
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SomeTextItem> TextItems { get; }

        public RelayCommand RemoveTextItem { get; }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.Zhan.question79147702.SomeTextWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.Zhan.question79147702"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SomeTextWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SomeTextViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TextItems}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeTextItem}">
                            <Button Content="Remove Item"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Command="{Binding RemoveTextItem, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

You can take my implementations of base classes from here: An example of my implementation of base classes: BaseInpc, RelayCommand, RelayCommandAsync, RelayCommand<T>, RelayCommandAsync<T>.
Another way to bind a command:
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeTextItem}">
            <Button Content="Remove Item"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.(local:SomeTextViewModel.RemoveTextItem),
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>




I'm trying to learn MVVM on my own. Also, I have not worked in large companies to realize the benefits of separation in MVVM. By the way, can you show me a small example?!


I got the impression that MVVM patterns are much more difficult to understand, and even more difficult to apply correctly.  On which site in which article could I find out about the fact that it is not correct to apply the code CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"?




In your example, you assign a DataContext to XAML. I also need to assign it when opening the window, that is, in CS. See the file PersonalTaskClassPicker.xaml.cs. In your example, you assign a DataContext to XAML. I also need to assign it when opening the window, that is, in CS. In my opinion, it is impossible to assign a DataContext to XAML and at the same time call the PersonalTaskClassPickerViewModel constructor with parameters. Or am I wrong?



I don't understand how all this affects my initial question about allocating a row in a DataGrid... after all, there are no ICommand commands involved at all?

